# C# financial charting library for Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, financial

I need a open-source/free C# tool or library that can do financial charting for a student project.  It needs to be able to do a open-high-low-close chart, and be able to graph various technical indicators that I calculate, all from within a Windows form.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try [ZedGraph](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/). You can do almost anything with that library.

Note: It's free and open source.

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft has released a [chart control](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en) for .NET 3.5.  You can get support at [this forum.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/MSWinWebChart/threads/)

Answer (score 0):

ChartFx from [SoftwareFX](http://www.softwarefx.com) is pretty good.  They are not free but do offer a 30 day trial that might work for a student project.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly open-source, but it is free (if you have a valid Office license). You can use Office Web Components to create *almost* any chart Excel can.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/owc11article.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This may give you clear and simple idea how to use Charts with free source.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/charting.aspx

Answer (score 0):

We use StockChartX from [www.modulusfe.com](http://www.modulusfe.com) - there are COM, WPF and Silverlight versions. Also Flash, HTML5, etc.

Comment: This is an expensive corporate product - hardly Open Source / Free as the OP requested.